# What are these arcade games in Ghostbusters 1984?

Tags: ghostbusters

During the 'We got one' scene in *Ghostbusters* we see 2 video games and a pinball machine but does anyone know what they are?

[image: unknown arcade games]

Comment: https://www.ghostbusters.net/forums/t/arcade-games-in-the-firehouse-2191/

Comment: https://www.gbfans.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37244

Comment: I think you mean "2 video games and a pinball machine". They are all arcade games.

Comment: @user14111 Just updated, thanks for pointing the out. I've always referred to video games as arcade, don't know if it's a UK thing? Anyone else like to comment?

Comment: For you pinballs aren't arcade games? Pinball machines were the mainstay of game arcades before video games were invented. Sadly, pinball machines have been mostly replaced by boring video games, which are easier and cheaper to maintain.

Comment: Pinball machines weren't commen in arcades in the U.K. When I was a kid

Comment: Yeah, also UK here and I've only ever heard "arcade machines" over here used to refer to video game machines, not pinball machines. Most arcades here (at least when I frequented them in the 80's/90's) were mainly just full of video games and sometimes gambling machines. Pinball machines were more common in seaside arcades, but those also tended to have a bigger mix of other machine types (including claw machines, coin pushers, etc).

Comment: Ah the seaside amusements.  2p waterfalls and fag reek, the 80s were great!

Comment: @Seamusthedog - I live by the coast and can assure you that the 2p machines are alive and well; no fag reek but if you miss it you can always step outside the arcade for a minute and stroll along to the smoking area of the nearest pub :-)

Comment: @Spratty I work in a seaside town and still find it funny these places still exist. Can't beat a chippy on a windy day, feet in the sand and winter coat on!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well as you see here:

https://arcadespecialties.com/arcade-games-for-sale/vintage-arcade-games/missile-command/

that's definitely the first machine shown.  The issue identifying it could have arisen from the fact that many of those games went through cabinet and art revisions constantly, and very well could have contributed to minor issues causing inconsistency.

Additionally, part of the reason pinball might not have been included in many arcades, was that new york and chicago and so on, some of the bigger major cities, had actually added pinball to prohibition lists from the 40s to the 70s, which would mean there's a very high chance any arcades built/renovated during that time, would have foregone pinball in an effort to avoid excess loss, had they been nationally prohibited.

read more about it here:
https://www.6sqft.com/pinball-prohibition-the-arcade-game-was-illegal-in-new-york-for-over-30-years/

Hope that helps :)

[[image: image for post][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnxZ7.jpg)
[[image: image for post][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mkfer.jpg)
[[image: image for post][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzEN8.jpg)
[[image: image for post][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqmEF.jpg)
[[image: image for post][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy1Lv.jpg)
[[image: image for post][7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRD2J.jpg)

Comment: nice one, re pinball it seems to be a UK thing or more a US thing. We don't get them much in the UK were as they are a cultural piece in the US

Answer (score 43):

Identified [elsewhere](https://www.gbfans.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=37244) as

[*Star Castle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Castle) (1980)

[image: Star Castle console]

[*Star Gazer*](https://www.ipdb.org/machine.cgi?id=2346) (1980)

> The pinball machine is called Star Gazer and is made by Stern:

[image: Star Gazer visual with a lady and her hoop]

[image: Star Gazer console]

---

The third machine appears to be [*Missile Command*](https://triosdevelopers.com/jason.eckert/missilecommand/info.html) (also 1980).

[image: Man leaning on Missile Command game]

Comment: The leftmost one looks nothing at all like that Jump Bug game.

Comment: I like the first two, but I'm not sure about Jump Bug. The title images on the box don't look anywhere similar... one is orange and Jump Bug is blue... though I have nothing to add right now in what it actually is!

Comment: @Odin1806 - The game was referenced in the comic serial; IDW Publishing Comics- Ghostbusters Get Real 1, which tends to back up the assertion that this is the game in question.

Comment: Looks like [Missile Command](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1930/2699/products/CAM00438_1024x1024.jpg?v=1494378693).

Comment: @Amy - I like that...

Comment: @Amy - You're not wrong. The logo matches

Comment: So where the hell are all these referenced to Jump Bug coming from?

Comment: This photo may be a little clearer for Missile Comand. https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Zme5yPNeL.jpg

Comment: Haha. That is curious... And I do like fact that forums and etc. have all been wondering this for years and then @Amy comes in here and solves it in no time...

Comment: To be fair, I only looked at the other answer, scratched my head, googled the game, then commented here.  Then I scratched my head again for good measure.  Credit should go to FuzzyBoots and head scratching.

Answer (score 32):

From [arcade-museum.com](https://forums.arcade-museum.com/showpost.php?s=1a147c99b270cf9cd81270cba27480b8&p=780126&postcount=7):

> It's Missile Command, Star Castle and Star Gazer. There was already another thread on this not too long ago. There's speculation that the Missle Command is converted into a Ms. Pac, due to the tinge of blue in the upper right of the Marquee. However you can clearly see Missle Command on the screen.